# Does a rectangle exist on any Jordan curve?

Tags: geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $C$ be a Jordan curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Does there exist points $P,Q,R,S$ on $C$ such that quadrangle $PQRS$ is a non-degenerate rectangle?

Comment: Yes, see [Matschke's survey](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/matschke/SurveyOnSquarePeg_extension14.pdf). Search the document for "Inscribed rectangles".

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that this problem has a name.

Comment: The link in eins6180 comment seems to be dead. I will add [Internet Archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20170808213916/http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/matschke/SurveyOnSquarePeg_extension14.pdf) and also link to [A Survey on the Square Peg Problem](http://www.ams.org/notices/201404/rnoti-p346.pdf) on Notices website. Wikipedia article on this: [Inscribed square problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem).